# neuralnet for multiple regression

Tags: r, neural-network, regression

I have a data frame, `Data`, which has 10 columns. First 6 are input values and the next 4 columns are output values.

```
head(Data)
x1        x2       x3       x4       x5      x6      y1       y2     y3       y4
200       400      1.8     100       50      10     3884     3.9    5.98     1.91
```

I want to use neural network to predict the values of outputs by using `neuralnet` package. When I use the following code, I am getting an error as following:

```
model <- neuralnet(Data[1:30,1:6], Data[1:30,7:10], data=Data, hidden=c(5,7), err.fct="ce", linear.output=FALSE)

Error in varify.variables(data, formula, startweights, learningrate.limit,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using neuralnet correctly.

1. First you should specify your formula like this:
   y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6
2. Since you are solving a regression problem, you should use default value "sse" For err.fct, instead of "ce"
3. Again, for regression problem, I believe you should choose linear activation function, thus there is no need to specify "linear.output=FALSE"

So you might want to call neuralnet like this:

model <- neuralnet(y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, data = Data, hidden = c(5,7))

Also you may need to rescale your input features before calling neuralnet.

Check out the document here:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf